# SQL Queries from Python Using Local CPU

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

When I run my SQL query from python it takes far longer than if I run it using heidiSQL, and I noticed that one core of my cpu is used 100%. I would have thought that SQL Server would do the heavy lifting, and there would just be a bunch of network traffic when the data is sent over.

I've put some code below from python, which takes over 5 minutes in python, but the same query from heidiSql takes 30 seconds.

1. What's happening here that I'm not understanding? i.e. Why does my computer use such CPU power for sql queries instead of the server
2. Is there some other way I should be running these queries so they don't take as long in python?

[My current code with run times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPJNx.png)

```
x_sql="""
SELECT *
FROM """+tableName+"""
WHERE dataTime BETWEEN '"""+startDate+"' and '"+endDate+"""'
"""

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=host,
                                     database=database,
                                     user=userName,
                                     password=password)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(x_sql)
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

Results from "SHOW CREATE TABLE"

```
CREATE TABLE `myDataTable` (
  `dataTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `P` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `AV` double NOT NULL,
  `Ratio` double NOT NULL,
  `AdjRatio` double NOT NULL,
  `SM` double NOT NULL,
  `SR` double NOT NULL,
  `DR` double NOT NULL,
  `Beta` double NOT NULL,
  `DF` double NOT NULL,
  `ED` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PIT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IW` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `G` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `DV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `BV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ED` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `DD` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SMIP` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `EEAV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `VCIP` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CEAV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `EAED` double DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IX_P_ED_dataTime_G` (`P`,`ED`,`dataTime`,`G`),
  KEY `IX_P_dataTime` (`P`,`dataTime`),
  KEY `dataTime` (`dataTime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Results from "SHOW INDEX FROM"
[SHOW INDEX FROM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzujC.png)

Comment: Are you retrieving many rows from the database? What happens when you comment the `fetchall` from the script?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE +tablename+; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM +tablename+;

Comment: I put the result from "SHOW INDEX FROM" in the post above, I couldn't figure out how to format a table here

Comment: I put the results from SHOW CREATE TABLE above in the post since they were too long to include as a commend

Comment: Removing the ```fetchall``` reduces the run fime to 30 seconds, so that is clearly where the issue is. I am returning quite a number of rows, but I had thought that would make the process bandwidth limited. Instead I am CPU limited.

Comment: Your table has no Primary Key.  Use of engine INNODB rather than MyISAM could provide significant performance improvement with data access.  This URL https://use-the-index-luke.com  could be important to review for concepts and examples.  Your row length appears to be under 256 but you have not shared with us 'number of rows' typically returned.  For additional discussion view profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.